# $G$ is obtained from the complete graph $K_n$ by deleting any one edge. Prove that $χ(G) =n−1$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let $G$ be a graph obtained from the complete graph $K_n$ by deleting any one edge.Prove that $χ(G) =n−1$

My work: $C=\{1,2,3,4.....n\}$  be a set of $n$ colors. Suppose that the edge removed was $e=(u,v)$ where $u,v ∈ V$ and $V$ is the set of $n$ vertices of $K_n$.

Color all vertices except $u$ and $v$ using $n-2$ colors from the set $C$. This leaves us with two colors in the set $C$ that are not used. Use one of these colors to color the vertex $u$. Since $u$ and $v$ are not connected, the same color can be used to color $v$. Hence we have colored $G$ using $n-1$ colors so $χ(G) =n−1$. Is this proof correct?

Comment: Your argument shows $\chi(G) \le n-1$. To show $\chi(G) > n-2$, you need to argue that you need more than $n-2$ colors, which should not be difficult.

Comment: $u$ has $n-2$ neighbors, all of which are connected to each other, so we need  $n-2$ colors to color all it's neighbors. This means that we can't use any of these $n-2$ colors to color $u$, so we have to use another color to color $u$. Then $χ(G) \ge n−1$. Which implies $χ(G) =n−1$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. More simply you can simply note $G$ contains a copy of $K_{n-1}$.

Comment: @angryavian If either you or the OP wanted to submit an answer, I’d happily +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof shows that $\chi(G) \leq n-1$. Because $G$ has $K_{n-1}$ as subgraph, $\chi(G) \geq n-1$. Hence $\chi(G)=n-1$. Alternatively, $\chi(G)\leq n-1$ by brooks' theorem.